# how to define oath2 scopes for multiple resources?

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm designing an API and have decided to use OAuth2 for controlling access to resources. I'm struggling with how to define the scopes for multiple resources and was hoping others might have solved the same or similar problem in the past.

I have 3 resources: A, B, C.

I have a client that has been given:

- READ access to A
- READ/WRITE access to B
- no access to C

How should I define the scopes in this case? I was thinking a request to get read access to A would be something like:

```
grant_type=client_credential&scope=A
```

A request to get write access to B would be:

```
grant_type=client_credential&scope=B+write
```

But then when you want both you get something like:

```
grant_type=client_credential&scope=A+B+write
```

which makes it look like you want write access to A and B!

OR ... maybe I should just forget about scopes and just check that the client has the appropriate access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define 4 scopes, `A_read`, `A_write`, `B_read` and `B_write`.

Comment: agreed, this is the solution that I've gone for. I'm defining scopes as a colon separated tuple of the form `{collection-name}:{access}` where `access` is either `read` or `write`.